# Can anyone inform me on how to calculate the area of the segmented region?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, area

I have done segmentation of tumor kind for the slice of the MR images . I want to calculate the area of the segmented region in Python. Can anyone help me in this regard?

[Pic of Segmented brain tumor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spSuf.jpg)

Comment: Area or Volume? Are your images 2D or 3D?

Comment: 2D images have no volume. Do you mean the area?

Comment: You're right, sorry I'm confused. Yeah it will be area.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to calculate the area of segment tumor part.

Comment: Your image does not appear to be segmented.  Is that the original or a segmented or thresholded image that has been colorized?  So threshold the image on the pink area using cv2.inRange() if you do not have a black and white binary version. Then count the number of (white) non-zero pixels in the image using np.count_nonzero().

Comment: Please share a proper image firstly! What did you search  and get till now ?

Answer (score 0):

Opencv has a function to calculate area of a contour.

```
contour = numpy.array([[[0,0]], [[10,0]], [[10,10]], [[5,4]]])
area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
```

[1. Contour Properties](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html)

[2. Contour Area](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

To find area you should convert desired area to 1 anf other area to zero. Then find all contour(or contours ) in your image. Finally calculate tumor area.

Comment: I just updated the picture I added to the question, in this case, can I still use opencv contours on this segmented pic to calculate the area of tumor ? thx

Comment: @ELİFÖZCAN why not. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just count the number *n* of white pixels in your segmented image and multiply it by the area of a single pixel in your image *A*. n*A is the area you are looking for. Of course, *A* should be converted to the unit of measurement that you prefer.